# YT video does not appear in the electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on an app and need the ability to add videos from YouTube.
The video tag doesn't show anything. There is no display via iframe either, but there is an error in the console:

```
(node:15336) electron: Failed to load URL: ( here is the link to the video ) with error: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

The only workable way I found was via YouTube embed, but it has its own disadvantage.
Firstly, it has no controller of its own and secondly, with frequent updates of the application (Ctrl + R), the RAM gets progressively busier

Comment: Something as simple as this doesn't work ? https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe

Comment: Again, but I have already done it through embed, but the problem is that the optimization begins to have problems (when you often reload the application, it loads RAM, as well as when minimizing and unfolding the application, video starts to lag).
Are there other ways, other than locally, to use the video in the app?

Comment: Sounds like an electron problem more than a problem with iframes then. You can pay to host your videos somewhere else which would allow you more freedom, such as compressing to a lower bitrate to improve performance and minimize ram usage.  If you are stuck with Youtube you might look into their API options. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters